# Regex: extract text between specified words or end of line

Tags: regex

I need to extract from a line value of Number, which are included between text "Number: " and "," or end of line.

I stopped on `(?<=Number: )(.*)(?=,)`
Thanks for help.

**Example lines:**

```
Nubmer: 2345, Id: 234
Id: 234, Nubmer: 2345, Key: aaa
Nubmer: 2345
```

**Target**: 2345

Comment: There is a typo in the example data, Nubmer should be Number right? Perhaps just match the digits `\bNumber: (\d+)(?:,|$)` https://regex101.com/r/1NYPHG/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your regex support lookbehinds, we can try:

```
(?<=\bNumber: ).*
```

If your engine does *not* support lookbehinds, we can instead use a capture group:

```
\bNumber: ([^,]+)
```

See the demo link below for the second version, where the target number appears in the first capture group, for each line.

### Demo